# How to average values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, average

So currently I have a dictionary of with keys and values set up like `{'25308': 'Male', '9960': 'Male', '85748': 'Female', '8523': 'Female'}`. My goal is to average the numbers with the coinciding value. I wish to have it be setup like ```{'17634': 'Male', '47135': 'Female'}. I also wish to use a for loop in order to average each key and value. I'm currently working on python 3.7. If anyone can give me insight or point me in the right direction it'd be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Do you mean to average all male values together separately and all female values separately?

Comment: Are there only `male` and `female` as values?

Comment: Yea thats exactly what I am looking for. I may need to simplify my dictionary a little bit more to tidy things up but yea. There are more values than just male and female as well

Answer (score 2):

Hey you could use list comprehension to filter for male and female

```
d = {'25308': 'Male', '9960': 'Male', '85748': 'Female', '8523': 'Female'}
male = [int(n) for n,k in d.items() if k=='Male']
female = [int(n) for n,k in d.items() if k=='Female']
```

Then you can calculate the average and write it into a dictionary

```
{
    str(sum(male)/len(male)): 'Male', 
    str(sum(female)/len(female)): 'Female'
}
```

Output:

```
{'17634.0': 'Male', '47135.5': 'Female'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure what you are asking for, but I believe you are wanting to average all the male and female keys.

I would do something like this

```
Dict = {'25308': 'Male', '9960': 'Male', '85748': 'Female', '8523': 'Female'}
maleTotal = 0
femaleTotal = 0
maleCount = 0
femaleCount = 0
for num, gender in Dict.items():
    if gender=='Male':
        maleCount+=1
        maleTotal+=int(num)
    else:
        femaleCount+=1
        femaleTotal+=int(num)

maleAverage = maleTotal / maleCount
femaleAverage = femaleTotal / femaleCount

print('Male Average: '+str(maleAverage)+' Female Average: '+str(femaleAverage))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate your dict to make it.

```
dict = {'25308': 'Male', '9960': 'Male', '85748': 'Female', '8523': 'Female'}
result = {}
for key in dict.keys():
    if dict[key] not in result:
        result[dict[key]] = 0
    result[dict[key]] += int(key)

output = {}
for key in result.keys():
    output[result[key]] = key
```

Answer (score 0):

## Approach 1

```
d = {
    '25308': 'Male',
    '9960' : 'Male',
    '85748': 'Female',
    '8523' : 'Female'}

def avg_if_match(stryng):
    stryng = stryng.lower()
    numerator = 0
    denominator = 0
    for number, gender in d.items():
        gender = gender.lower()
        if (gender in stryng) or (stryng in gender):
            numerator += number
            denominator += 1
    return numerator/denominator

female_avg = avg_if_match("fem")
```

## Approach 2

```
def is_male(s):
    return (s[0].lower() == "m")  

def is_female(s):
    return (s[0].lower() == "f")

male_data = filter(is_male, d)
male_avg = sum(male_data ) /len(male_data)

female_data = filter(is_female, d)
female_avg = sum(female_data ) /len(female_data)
```